# How to store huge amount of data in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a simple basic question. Assume i have a large website like facebook, gmail and so on. this site probably save hundreds of gigabytes information every day. My question is how these sites save this large information in their database(Because of database capacity). Is there only one database? Is there only one server for this site? If there is another server and database, how they can communicate with each others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are clearly not using one computer...

The system behind such large sites are very complex, and distributed across datacenters. See - http://royal.pingdom.com/2010/06/18/the-software-behind-facebook/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site for info on various architectures employed by those sites (and this site): http://highscalability.com/all-time-favorites/

Most of these sites have gone with a strategy called NoSQL - that is they don't use traditional RDBM databases, but instead have created their own object relationship frameworks which have the ability to be persisted.  This strategy works well at large scale as it drops a number of constraints which would seriously impact performance of traditional DB methods.  However this generally comes at the cost of a lowering of reliability, which is generally considered acceptable for those sites' scenarios.

ps. if your question's general interest then no worries. If you're trying to build a highly scalable application hold off and consider it for a moment - are you going to be serving a significant percentage of the population of the world, or are you writing a site for maybe a few thousand users. If it's the latter you don't need Facebook style scaling; invest your effort and resources elsewhere. If it's the former start small then evolve your system, bringing in investment and expertise as your user base grows.